# Cocoa event loop blocks while tracking a menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, core-foundation

I maintain a legacy OSX application that instead of calling NSApplicationMain() to process events, runs an event loop on the main thread that looks like this:

```
...
do {

        event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask untilDate:distantPast
                        inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode dequeue:YES];
        [self handleEvent:event];
        }
    } while(event != nil);
...
```

Everything works until I activate the application's menu. Once the menu is active, nextEventMatchingMask blocks forever. I can see in lldb that osx starts another modal event loop (carbon?) which causes the cococa's one to block:

```
frame #2: 0x00007fff92748eb4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
frame #3: 0x00007fff9274837b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1371
frame #4: 0x00007fff92747bd8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
frame #5: 0x00007fff8c11c56f HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
frame #6: 0x00007fff8c11c2ea HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
frame #7: 0x00007fff8c17568a HIToolbox`AcquireNextEventInMode + 54
frame #8: 0x00007fff8c172e2b HIToolbox`IsUserStillTracking(MenuSelectData*, unsigned char*) + 173
frame #9: 0x00007fff8c172a41 HIToolbox`TrackMenuCommon(MenuSelectData&, unsigned char*) + 1661
frame #10: 0x00007fff8c1803c1 HIToolbox`MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned int, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) + 510
frame #11: 0x00007fff8c1800fe HIToolbox`_HandleMenuSelection2 + 446
frame #12: 0x00007fff8a9a8de0 AppKit`_NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 277
frame #13: 0x00007fff8a8dfd0d AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 1828
frame #14: 0x00007fff8a8def68 AppKit`-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent this behaviour ?
Unfortunately I cannot rewrite the application so I need a quick and dirty solution to run the main thread while the menu is active.

Comment: Are you able to move it to the newer model, perhaps taking code from a newly-created Cocoa App?

Comment: What do you expect to happen while menu tracking is in progress? What event would be returned to you? How would you handle that event such that it would allow the user to use the menu?

Comment: Ideally I want nextEventMatchingMask to dequeue carbon menu events also and post them back to the designated handler so both cocoa and carbon would be happy

Comment: That's what it's doing. It can't **return** the Carbon menu events, because it returns an `NSEvent` and those can't be represented by an `NSEvent`.

Comment: I understand,so my next question is it possible to poll on carbon events similarly the way I poll on cocoa events?